# How to modify a WordPress post's markup?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

On [this site](http://www.londonadvertising.com/2011) I'm working on  if you scroll down to the 'News' section there are 2 posts.

I wanted to contain the posts section within a set height of 300px so you will basically need to scroll down and if I add some CSS of overflow: scroll this will enable the scrolling.

How do I go about modifying this in WordPress for the posts?

I can not seem to be able to find the CSS for this area as it appears the whole news section isn't in a div of it's own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hide the scrollbar you can just in css:

```
overflow:hidden
```

Otherwise, you need to find the template and put a condition in that, like:

```
if(posts->type=='news')
   echo <div id="news">...;
```

then apply css on the id news.